# how to make a javascript array be the choices in an <option> tag

Tags: javascript

title is self explanatory i think..

is there anyway to make a list of about **300** items in an array be the choices in

`<option>ARRAY DATA</option></select>`

Comment: Yes.... but 300 element in *one* select list seems to be very user unfriendly. You should think about another structure to represent the data/choices.

Comment: @Felix - Actually, that's sounds about right for a country selection field...

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: Yes, I thought about that too... true.

Comment: @Shawn - the code given will do what you ask but you better consider using AJAX solutions that will show textbox with auto complete. Here is one example: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var s = document.getElementById('id_of_select_tag');
var ar = [1,2,3];
for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = ar[i];
  option.value = ar[i];
  s.options[s.options.length] = option;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erick/9Dj3j/3

Comment: can you maybe explain the last line of s.options[s.options.length] = option; a little better.. i find it confusing.. it works fine on jfiddle but my browsers are saying object is required

Comment: select element has an [HTMLOptionsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionsCollection) object attribute, it supports indexes. Code is basically pushing `<option>` to its parent `<select>` HTMLOptionsCollection attribute. `s.options.length` starts at `0` and so forth. I replaced `s.options[s.options.length]` with `s.options[i]` and output remains the same. An alternative syntax for this, is `s.options.add(option)` which is probably more readable.

Comment: nice. i see how it's working now. i am just wondering why if i take the exact code working in jfiddle and upload it locally it gives me object undefined. .

Comment: i am working with strings instead of numbers in the array.. but i don't think that should affect much

Comment: you need to have `<select id="id_of_select_tag"></select>`

Comment: check your html, `id="multi2"` to `id="multi"`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dj3j/42/ .. working in jfiddle not browser..  and yes sorry .. i did catch that error

Comment: You might need to trigger it via an event. You can wrap it in a function triggered by `onload`, something like this: `window.onload = function () { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Does the JavaScript array really have to be generated from the choices in the `<select>`? Particularly, can't it be the other way around?

If you can get away with generating the contents of the list from the array, all you'll need to do is iterate over the array and output the list elements. I'm pretty sure you could even do that without even touching `document.write()` and its kin, but JavaScript DOM manipulation is far from what I know best.